# Which mode should I use for RDFa code in emacs?

Tags: emacs, rdfa

For all my typing tasks I use emacs.

Which mode should I use for [RDFa code](http://rdfa.info/)?

The nearest I can find is the [n3-mode-for-emacs](https://github.com/kurtjx/n3-mode-for-emacs). But there are some small differences.

Comment: As far as I know, RDFa is effectively a bunch of attributes that live inside tags in an XML document, so `nxml-mode` seems a logical choice. What, specifically, are you looking for in an RDFa mode? Completion?

Comment: @Chris No, I can live without completions. Indentations are my  highest priority.

Comment: Again, if RDFa indeed lives inside XML tags, what is `nxml-mode` missing? Can you add an example to your question?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, looks like I misunderstood some text from another source and nxml-mode should be fine for rdfa code. I am going to close the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it originated from a misunderstanding on the part of OP.

Comment: The question might have originated from a misunderstanding, but I think it still has value on SO. I have added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa):

> **RDFa** (or [Resource Description Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) in Attributes) is a [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C) Recommendation that adds a set of attribute-level extensions to [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) and various XML-based document types for embedding rich [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) within Web documents.

Since RDFa lives inside HTML and XML attributes it makes sense to use an HTML or XML mode, depending on the format of the base file.

`nxml-mode` works very well for XML and XHTML. `html-mode` or [`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org/) would be a good choice for XHTML and HTML.